# How to put sentences in tables 2

Tags: tables

I want to create a table using LaTeX. The table looks like this:

[image: ![(1stExperiment.png)]

I was able to manage make a table, but it is not what I envisioned. It looks like this:

[image: (1stExperiment2.png)]

The code I used looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\sffamily\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}| }
\hline
Appointment---related information & Did the information gets posted on the Google Calendar? & & Notes\\
\cline{2-3}
 & Yes & No & 
\hline
%\multirow{2}{=}
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:tab1}
\caption{Tabulated app's responses to different usernames and passwords.}
\vspace{60mm}
\end{document}
```

My question is:

How can we make a table using LaTeX that looks like the first picture above, and to look more attractive?

Comment: There are quite some issues with your code. You can't use `\label` prior to `\caption`, this would lead to a wrong reference. It is considered best practice to put the `\label` inside of the argument of  `\caption` (be careful not to introduce spaces around it by accident). Also you're using `\caption` outside of a floating environment (should be used inside of `table` or `figure`, there is `\captionof` provided by KOMA-script, the `capt-of` package or the `caption` package to circumvent this restriction). You're missing a `\\ ` after the `& yes & no &` line.

Comment: Additonally, using `tabularx` without an `X` column does not make too much sense. As you can see, all horizontal lines are cut off to fit into the linewidth, while your table is significantly wider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following MWE contains two different suggestions. The first one is very similar to the sketch in your question. For this I have used an `X` type column from the `tabularx` package as well as some `multirow` commands to vertically center table entries.

The second suggestion uses a lot less lines: I have removed all vertical lines as well as most horizontal lines and replaced the remaining by `booktabs`'s rules. I have also tried to shorten one of the column headers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,multirow,booktabs}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sffamily\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|C{1cm-\tabcolsep}|C{1cm-\tabcolsep}|c|}
\hline
\multirow{6}{=}{\centering Appointment-related information} & \multicolumn{2}{C{2cm}|}{Did the information gets posted on the Google Calendar?}  & \multirow{6}{*}{\centering Notes}\\
\cline{2-3}
 & Yes & No & \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
a different longer entry & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:tab1}
\caption{Tabulated app's responses to different usernames and passwords.}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\sffamily\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XC{1cm-\tabcolsep}C{1cm-\tabcolsep}c}
\toprule
\multirow{4}{=}{\centering Appointment-related information} & \multicolumn{2}{C{2cm}}{Info posted on the Google Calendar?}  & \multirow{4}{*}{\centering Notes}\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
 & Yes & No & \\
\midrule
Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

a different longer entry & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\

Meeting at 6 & \checkmark &  & Correct response  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:tab1}
\caption{Tabulated app's responses to different usernames and passwords.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The column specifier p, with a width in cm always works well for me.

[image: table using p{Ncm}]

```
%   
The following table~\ref{tbl:potential_cal} lists all calibration variables so far considered.
{   
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Example Calibration Variables} % title of Table
%\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{|| p{3cm} | l | c | p{6cm} ||} \hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
 \textbf{Name} & \textbf{\oc{20}} & \textbf{\oc{60}} & \textbf{Comments}          \\ \hline
\hline

 Offsets of Something     & YES & POSS & Should be very close to $\frac{V_{cc}}{2}$ \\ \hline
 Offsets of Something even longer    & YES & POSS & Should be very close to $\frac{V_{cc}}{2}$ \\ \hline
 Offsets of Something even longer and more    & YES & POSS & Should be very close to $\frac{V_{cc}}{2}$ and something else as well in the text \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:potential_cal}
\end{table}
}
```

~