# How to put sentences in table 4

Tags: tables

I was following the answer found in this question [How to put sentences in table 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451992/how-to-put-sentences-in-table-3) and I just changed the contents of the table. I thought it's gonna be straightforward because I didn't touch the commands used there.

What happens is after I changed the sentences in the table without touching the commands used to generate the table, the PDF looks like this:

[image]

I really don't think the @ symbol is a very special character in Latex but why the email address' name didn't fit itself in the table? If I'm going to erase the @ symbol in the email address name, the name just fits in the table. I don't get it.

The code I used to generate the PDF is shown below...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sffamily\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C{3cm}|C{1.5cm-\tabcolsep}|C{1.5cm-\tabcolsep}|X|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}[-.5cm]{\centering Email addresses} &                             \multicolumn{2}{C{3cm}|}{Did the information gets posted on the Google Calendar?}  & \multirow{2}{=}[-0.5cm]{\centering Notes}\\
\cline{2-3}
 & Yes & No & \\
\hline
rinshi246\@ gmail.com &  & \checkmark  & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
devspecsniper@gmail.com &  & \checkmark  & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
idislikeperiods@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
335basurahan@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
lubotsabaso@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
paltik357@gmail.com & \checkmark &  & The information gets posted on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
storethefileshere@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if it was a time interval. It should be corrected.  \\
\hline
fitzmerlduron@outlook.com & \checkmark &  & The information gets posted on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
screwelectronics@yahoo.com &  & \checkmark & The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if it is a weekday and time is mentioned. It should be corrected.  \\
\hline
gapalanay227@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if the information is enough. The information shown in this context must be recognized by the app and should be corrected.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Google Calendar's responses to different email accounts.}
\label{table-test6}
\end{table}
\vspace{60mm}


\end{document}
```

How will I correct this problem?

Comment: If you want help with an error you should always show the exact error message from the log. Don't post (or even look at) the typeset output, TeX makes no attempt to make sensible typeset output after an error, its error recovery (if you scroll past the error) is designed to allow syntax checking of the rest of the document, not to make a usable document.

Answer (score 4):

Your example does not compile for me (`C` column type undefined in the example) and the dimensions seemingly not calculated. In my understanding you do not even need this extra column type as `array` provides `w{x}{l}` (which makes a box of alignment x and width l, so `w{c}{1.5cm}` is a box of 1.5cm width centering its content). I also removed the overprinting of the cell in the middle.

Btw: As you are using `twocolumn` you should consider using `table*` because your table is too wide for one column.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sffamily\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|wc{\dimexpr1.5cm-\tabcolsep}|wc{\dimexpr1.5cm-\tabcolsep}|X|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Email addresses} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering}p{3cm}|}{Did the information gets posted on the Google Calendar?}  & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering Notes}\\
\cline{2-3}
 & Yes & No & \\
\hline
rinshi246\@ gmail.com &  & \checkmark  & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
devspecsniper@gmail.com &  & \checkmark  & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
idislikeperiods@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
335basurahan@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
lubotsabaso@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
paltik357@gmail.com & \checkmark &  & The information gets posted on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
storethefileshere@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if it was a time interval. It should be corrected.  \\
\hline
fitzmerlduron@outlook.com & \checkmark &  & The information gets posted on Google Calendar.  \\
\hline
screwelectronics@yahoo.com &  & \checkmark & The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if it is a weekday and time is mentioned. It should be corrected.  \\
\hline
gapalanay227@gmail.com &  & \checkmark & The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if the information is enough. The information shown in this context must be recognized by the app and should be corrected.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Google Calendar's responses to different email accounts.}
\label{table-test6}
\end{table}
\vspace{60mm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: worth mentioning that `w` is new so you need an `array.sty` from this year.

Comment: it will be more clear if you write `w{c}{\dimexpr1.5cm-\tabcolsep}` instead of `wc{\dimexpr1.5cm-\tabcolsep}` :-). and `\noindet` before `\centering` in table hasn't any sense .

Comment: @Zarko That might be, but being German wc simply sounds much more interesting ;)

Comment: @TeXnician, well, than in my language should write 00 :-). i still encourage that (at least at on beginning of new version of the `array` package) we keep the official syntax (i must confess that i understood your code after reading David comment).

Comment: @TeXnician Does "Why are you loading booktabs twice?" remind you on something? :-)

Comment: @KeksDose Yes, but fortunately, I have the excuse of copying the OP's code ;)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the definition of the `C` column type is the same as in [your earlier query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451660/), I would like to make the following suggestions:

- Change the column type of the first column from `C` to `l`. There is simply no good way to introduce line breaks in email addresses.
- Switch from `table` to `table*`.
- Change `\@` to `@` to typeset "at" characters.
- Since you're loading the `booktabs` package, make use of its capabilities, i.e., replace all instances of `\hline` with `toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule`. And, get rid of all vertical rules.
- Since you're using a sans-serif font for the body of the table, I think it would be a good idea to use sans-serif for the caption as well. Since you're loading the `caption` package, just issue a directive such as `\captionsetup{font=sf}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,amssymb,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451660/ for def. of "C"
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*} % since 'twocolumn' option is in use
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,font=sf}
\sffamily%\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
%\noindent
%\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
         l
         C{\dimexpr1.5cm-\tabcolsep\relax}
         C{\dimexpr1.5cm-\tabcolsep\relax}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X   % left-alignment rather than full justification
         @{}}
\toprule
Email addresses & 
\multicolumn{2}{C{3cm}}{Did information get posted on Google Calendar?}  
& Notes\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
 & Yes & No & \\
\midrule
rinshi246@gmail.com &  & \checkmark  
& The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
devspecsniper@gmail.com &  & \checkmark  
& The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
idislikeperiods@gmail.com &  & \checkmark 
& The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
335basurahan@gmail.com &  & \checkmark 
& The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
lubotsabaso@gmail.com &  & \checkmark 
& The time is not specified whether it is am or pm, so it does not appear on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
paltik357@gmail.com & \checkmark &  
& The information gets posted on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
storethefileshere@gmail.com &  & \checkmark 
& The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if it was a time interval. It should be corrected.  \\
\addlinespace
fitzmerlduron@outlook.com & \checkmark &  
& The information gets posted on Google Calendar.  \\
\addlinespace
screwelectronics@yahoo.com &  & \checkmark 
& The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if it is a weekday and time is mentioned. It should be corrected.  \\
\addlinespace
gapalanay227@gmail.com &  & \checkmark 
& The information didn't plot on the Google Calendar even if the information is enough. The information shown in this context must be recognized by the app and should be corrected.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Google Calendar's responses to different email accounts.}
\label{table-test6}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```